# How do I install Ubuntu 22.10 on a Linux Mint 20.3 system?

Tags: system-installation

I'm a Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon user. I have a spare SSD and want to install Ubuntu 22.10 on it.

What do I need to do?

This will be a Clean Install and I don't want to save any files.

Comment: No you don't; you can modify your existing boot loader to boot *live* systems that exist on your existing drive (SSD) by modification to your `grub` boot loader, but that is a lot more work than just writing the ISO you want to install to thumb-drive, and just booting it and installing from thumb-drive media.  You can also use any other media your machine can boot from (*including magnetic tape, SD/MMC or any media if your box will boot from it*)

Comment: Is existing install UEFI? Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub's UEFI boot files to ESP - efi system partition on first drive. For most that is ok. But if external drive or user wants total separation, you have to manually partition in advance or do a work around.  Multiple work arounds posted:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Remove esp flag from Windows or other first drive install before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: I would recommend unplugging the Mint drive before proceeding, (you cant break something that is not there). Install Ubuntu using guiverc's link above. replace the Mint drive and `sudo update-grub` to put Mint on Ubuntu's GRUB menu.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have an SSD that you wish to install Ubuntu 22.10 to. This is a simple install. Ubuntu has an excellent [step by step guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview).

You need a USB drive (on which to flash the live environment), and then use that to install the OS itself. The iso is available at on [Ubuntu Desktop OS Download Page](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=22.10&architecture=amd64).